# ExpandableLayout animation not smooth

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using cachapa/ExpandableLayout in Dialog layout, but I faced some unexpected animation. I mean, the expandable layout does not move in and moves out smoothly, but suddenly.

[Click to screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lXvX.gif)

As you can see the picture above, I place the dialog at the BOTTOM of the screen using `Utils.setWindowGravity(getWindow(), Gravity.BOTTOM);`. If I change it to TOP, the animation works [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM2tL.gif). But in my case, I should set it to BOTTOM. How can I solve it?

res/layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--other views-->

    <net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout
        android:id="@+id/expand_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:el_duration="500"
        app:el_expanded="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                style="@style/EditText_BorderedMiddle_Grey_F"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/dialog_categories_hintname"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                style="@style/ImageView_FilledMiddle_Blue_F_50"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_check_white_48dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout>

    <!--other views-->
</LinearLayout>
```

java

```
public class CategoriesDialog extends AppCompatDialog {
    //other codes
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Utils.setWindowGravity(getWindow(), Gravity.BOTTOM);
        //...
    }
    @OnClick(R.id.add)
    public void onAddClick() {
        expandAdd.toggle();
    }
}

public class Utils {
    public static void setWindowGravity(Window window, int gravity) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes = window.getAttributes();
        attributes.gravity = gravity;
        window.setAttributes(attributes);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add animatelayoutchanges=true in top linear layout

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried, but still not work.

Comment: check your custom class code or library doc

Comment: If I place my dialog to Gravity.TOP, it works fine, but what if I should place it to Gravity.BOTTOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to be changing your dialog's size like that. From my own experience, changing the height of a Dialog is very inneficient, and even if the animation was working properly it would be incredibly janky.

I recommend that you instead implement that interface as a custom overlay that you place over your entire UI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrim"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#6000">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Add" />

    <net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout
        android:id="@+id/expand_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:el_duration="500"
        app:el_expanded="false"
        app:el_parallax="0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:windowBackground"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_48dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout>

    <!--other views-->
</FrameLayout>
```

Set R.id.scrim as a click listener that closes your ExpandableLayout and an ExpansionListener that hides the entire overlay when expansionRatio is zero.
That way you can perfectly replicate the behaviour you're looking for with the Dialog, but with much better performance.